# Inscribed circle $O_1$ is tangent to outer circle and its secant AB. Prove the circumcircle of the triangle $ABO_1$ bisects segment of tangent points.

Tags: geometry

$\odot{O_1}$ is inside $\odot{O}$ and they are tangent at $P$. $AB$ is a secant of $\odot{O}$ and is tangent to $\odot{O_1}$ at $Q$. Prove that the circumcircle of $\triangle{AO_1B}$ bisects $PQ$. i.e.: $PR=QR$

There are some conclusions on this type of inscribed circle. For example, the extended PQ will bisect $\overset{\huge\frown}{AB}$ of the outer circle $\odot{O}$, [details can be checked here](https://publications.azimpremjiuniversity.edu.in/2022/1/Circles%20Inscribed%20in%20Segments_At%20Right%20Angle%20July%2019.pdf), but still a bit far away to the statement of this problem.

[image]

THE KEY POINT IS: show that $ABO_1R$ is cyclic.

You can make $R$ to be the midpoint of $PQ$ but you need show that it is on the circle. Why it must be on the circumcircle of $\triangle{ABO_1}$? What about some other circle like this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, let the tangent at $P$ meets the extension of $BA$ at $C$.

Instead of drawing circle $O_1AB$, we let $PQ$ intersect $CO_1$ at $R$.

Note that $R$ is the mid-point of $PQ$,

As the OP mentioned, the key is to prove that $O_1, R, A, B$ are concyclic.

Proof:

For circle $O$, note that $$CA \times CB = CP^2   \tag{1}$$

Note that $\Delta CRP \sim \Delta CPO_1$,
$$\therefore \frac{CR}{CP}=\frac{CP}{CO_1}$$
Hence $$CP^2=CR \times CO_1  \tag{2}$$

$(1), (2) \implies$
$$CA \times CB = CR \times CO_1$$
Hence $$\frac{CA}{CR}=\frac{CO_1}{CB}   \tag{3}$$

$(3)$ together with the fact that $\angle RCA= \angle BCO_1$ is a common angle implies that

$$\Delta RCA \sim \Delta BCO_1$$

$$\therefore \angle ARC = \angle O_1BC$$

Thus $O_1, R, A, B$ are concyclic.

This means that circle $O_1AB$ will cut $PQ$ at $R$, the mid-point of $PQ$.

Comment: This approach works. It's the power of the point C on three circles that are equal to each other. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$O_1Q $ is perpendicular to AB at Q. A tangent at P on the ciecle $O_1$ or$O$ meets the extension of BA at E and $PE=EQ$, also $O_1P=O_1Q$  so in kite $O_1PEQ$ we have $O_1E$  perpendicular to the chord PQ of the circle $O_1$ and in this way it bisects PQ.

Now if G is on the circle we must have:

$FG\times EO_1=EA\times EB$

Also:

$PE^2=EG\times EO_1=EG(EG+GO_1)=EG^2+EG\times GO_1$

Triangle $PEO_1$ is rightangled at P and PE if it's altitude, therefore $EG\times GO_1=PG^2$ that is we have:

$PE^2= EG^2+PG^2$

which is true, this means G is on the circle,hence the circle bisects PQ.

note that in my figure G is for R in your figure.

Comment: Yes, $G$ is the midpoint of $PQ$ but it does not mean $G$ is on the circumcircle of $\triangle{ABO_1}$.Need prove that the insect of $EO_1$ and $PQ$ is on the circumcircle of $\triangle{ABO_1}$. Say, all you said is valid in this diagram but $G$ is not on the circle: https://imgur.com/a/sb8P3Ku

Comment: @rne, I included the reason for coincidence of G on the circle.

Comment: You are still proving the relationship between PE and EG and PG. They form right angle triangle yeah, but it has nothing to do with the circumcircle of $\triangle{ABO_1}$. https://imgur.com/a/sb8P3Ku, you can use this figure to prove why G is on the circle :-)

Comment: Or you can use this figure: https://imgur.com/a/tH1UJ6n. You don't need the circle in your proof.

Comment: I used the power of point E to the circumcircle of the triangle $O_1AB$, how it has nothing to do with that? If know the right solution, why you din't mention it as an answer?

Comment: I used the power of point E to the circumcircle of the triangle $O_1AB$, how it has nothing to do with that? If know the right solution, why you din't mention it as an answer?In fact we have: $EG\times EO_1=EA\times EB$

Comment: EG×EO1=EA×EB not mentioned in the proof? @sirous

Comment: I did not know the answer when i posted the question. From some answers I think it's correct to use the power of point.